# How to make a parallel wrapper in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to run steps in parallel and find out which one failed. The problem with parallel is after the run you don't know which run step failed. So I thought that id use `sh` with `returnStatus:true` to set a reference instead of using ugly try catch blocks.

```
tests = (0 == sh( script:"touch tests; ls -l tests", returnStatus:true ))
```

but wrap that up so it looks more like this.

```
wrapStep("touch icc; ls -l icc", passByRef, 'icc')
if ( passByRef.icc ) {do stuff}
```

that makes the pipeline code neater because all your build state can be represented in one object with properties.

This demo scripted pipeline demonstrates this concept working.

```
class SuccessType { 
    boolean icc 
    boolean gcc
    boolean tests
}

def wrapStep(String cmd, Object reference, String key){ 
    reference[key] = 0 == sh( script:cmd, returnStatus:true )
    return reference[key]
}


node {
    def passByRef = new SuccessType()
    sh "rm -f *" // remove files from the workspace
    passByRef.tests = 0 == sh( script:"touch tests; ls -l tests", returnStatus:true )
    wrapStep("touch icc; ls -l icc", passByRef, 'icc')
    wrapStep("touch foo; ls -l gcc", passByRef, 'gcc')

    println "tests state is " + passByRef.tests
    println "icc state is " + passByRef.icc
    println "gcc state is " + passByRef.gcc
}
```

But I cant get this to work in parallel. Doing this

```
parallel( 
  'icc' : wrapStep('build icc', passByRef, 'icc'),
  'gcc' : wrapStep('build gcc', passByRef, 'gcc')
)
```

Blows up in an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [try parallel, org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@1a5f3fc7]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:588)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:521)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:220)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1278)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1172)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:24)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:84)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor434.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:370)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:282)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:270)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Ive tried a lot but I'm out of ideas. Does anyone know how to overcome this ?

Edit : the demo will need Groovy Sandbox unchecked else it will complain about not allowing static method calls.

Comment: Oh and i suspect its got to do with what is returned from wrapStep or how to encase wrapStep properly for parallel.

Comment: I suggest that you'll use the 'parallelPhase' class of https://github.com/TikalCI/tci-library with 'stepsSequence' instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap the parallel blocks with closures

```
parallel( 
  'icc' : { wrapStep('build icc', passByRef, 'icc') },
  'gcc' : { wrapStep('build gcc', passByRef, 'gcc') }
)
```

Comment: doing that does not work for me. I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [try parallel, org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@70e6c998]` error.

Comment: Can you share your whole pipeline? It seems definitely as invalid syntax